# How to display big Emojis in UILabel?

Tags: ios, swift, emoji

I try to show big Emoji on UIView using UILabel, but when I increase the font size it loses quakity of the Emoji image.

[image]

Is it possible to display Emoji 200x200px without losing quality?

Comment: I've had success in the past by putting the emoji in an html doc in a UIWebView and increasing the font size using CSS, then make the webview have a transparent background in Obj-c and in javascript.

Comment: @Eugene did you finally found a solution to this problem?